# Mac App Store only downloading at only 12-20 kbps?

Tags: mac-appstore

So, I am trying to download an app from the Mac App Store and the download is only coming through at 12-20 kbps. I noticed it was also affecting iTunes downloads as well but all other applications seem to be working at full speed. What can I do to alleviate this problem?

Comment: Although the store is behind load balancers and CDN, it's capable of hundreds of times the bandwidth for individual downloads in the US. Have you tried another connection / ISP to the internet? Can you run a trace route to see where the traffic is passing presently?

Answer (score 1):

The Mac App Store uses the same servers as iTunes downloads use. Something on your network may be throttling traffic to those servers (this is common in company networks). You might be able to work around it using a Virtual Private Network (VPN) service.